# How to trim whitespace from a SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I'm new-ish to SwiftUI. I'm trying to trim whitespace from text entered in a TextField.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = "" {
        didSet {
            print("didSet, name = '\(name)'")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Name", text: $name, onEditingChanged: { (didBegin) in
                if !didBegin {
                    print("editing did end. name before trim = '\(name)'")
                    name = name.trimWhiteSpace()
                    print("editing did end. name after trim = '\(name)'")
                }
            }, onCommit: {
                print("committed. name before trim = '\(name)'")
                name = name.trimWhiteSpace()
                print("committed. name after trim = '\(name)'")
            })
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Text("name = '\(name)'")
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
    }
}
extension String {
    func trimWhiteSpace() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

When I enter a name with leading and trailing spaces and hit Return here's the output:

> committed. name before trim = ' Bob ' <- leading and trailing spaces
> didSet, name = 'Bob' <- trim was called, looks good
> committed. name after trim = 'Bob' <- name appears to be trimmed
> editing did end. name before trim = ' Bob ' <- but wait, it's not trimmed
> didSet, name = 'Bob' <- trim was called (again), looks good (again)
> editing did end. name after trim = 'Bob' <- name appears to be trimmed

Question 1: Notice that `name` is trimmed in `onCommit`. But right after that `onEditingChanged` runs and name is no longer trimmed. That seems very strange to me. Can anyone explain that?

Furthermore after hitting Return, here is the view still with the leading and trailing spaces:
[image]

Question 2: Does this indicate that `name` is actually not trimmed at this point? Or is `name` trimmed but somehow the view has simply not been updated? Either way, how do I get this to work?

Comment: The `name` is actually trimmed, but the view is not updated as expected because the TextField's `onEditingChanged` closure is called twice, once by `onCommit` and once by `onEditingChanged`. Updating the `onEditingChanged` closure should fix your issue is what I surmise

Comment: the `onEditingChanged` is deprecated, I recommend relying on `onCommit`. Definitely not both at the same time. If it's desired to change input as user types, then you can use `focused` in combination with `onChange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init(_:text:onEditingChanged:onCommit:)` deprecated (see [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:text:oneditingchanged:oncommit:)-588cl)) so I would implement using Apple's suggestion by using `focusState` for the `onEditingChanged` behavior.
Following example trims whitespace when focus changes for the `TextField`:

```
@State private var name = "" {
    didSet {
        print("didSet, name = '\(name)'")
    }
}
@FocusState private var focusState: Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .focused($focusState)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .onChange(of: focusState) {
                self.name = name.trimWhiteSpace()
            }
        Text("name = '\(name)'")
    }
    .padding([.leading, .trailing])
}
```

Comment: This works but I prefer `onSubmit` for the trimming because then it only happens once on the way out.